# TypeScript lambda functions with optional parameters

Tags: typescript

I am having problems when defining a lambda function that accepts an optional parameter. The strange part is that if I use the full "function" syntax the anonymous function works, but the lambda shorthand/arrow syntax produces errors such as the following:

- The name 'a' does not exist in the current scope
- Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
- Expected ')'

Example:

```
(function (a, b?) => { console.log(a, b); })("a"); // OK
((a, b?) => { console.log(a, b); })("a", "b");     // Errors
((a, b) => { console.log(a, b); })("a", "b");      // OK
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug in the compiler and is getting fixed right now [v0.8]. Lambdas currently give error messages with optional and rest parameters. Please use the long function syntax if this is a blocking issue.

Comment: Is this logged on the project page? If so, please provide a link and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 3):

There's currently a bug with optional parameter annotation in fat arrow lambda expressions.